# python I got an error dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required in my python program

Tags: python

```
def steps_to_enter_cycle(f, x0):


    """
    Determine the length of the intial part of the orbit of `x0` under `f` befor
    e
    it enters a periodic cycle.
    Arguments:
    `f` - a function (should take one integer argument and return an integer
    )
    `x0` - a value of the type that `f` accepts as its argument
    Returns:
    The number of elements of the orbit of `f` before the first value that
    repeats.
    Example: Suppose that applying f repeatedly to start value 11 gives this seq
    uence:
    11, 31, 12, 5, 6, 2, 8, 19, 17, 8, 19, 17, 8, 19, 17, 8, ...
    Then the return value of steps_to_enter_cycle(f,11) would be 6, because ther
    e are 6
    values in the intial segment of the orbit (i.e. 11, 31, 12, 5, 6, 2) which a
    re followed by
    a periodic cycle.
    (If the orbit of `x0` doesn't end up in a cycle, it's ok for this function t
    o run forever
    trying to find one.)
    """
    d = orbit_data(f,x0)
    initial_value = dict("intial")
    return len(initial_value)



def eventual_cycle(f, x0):


    """
    Return the periodic cycle that the orbit of x0 ends up in as a list.
    Arguments:
    `f` - a function (should take one integer argument and return an integer
    )
    `x0` - a value of the type that `f` accepts as its argument
    Returns:
    The earliest segment from the orbit of `x0` under `f` that repeats
    indefinitely thereafter, as a list.
    Example: Suppose that applying f repeatedly to start value 11 gives this seq
    uence:
    11, 31, 12, 5, 6, 2, 8, 19, 17, 8, 19, 17, 8, 19, 17, 8, ...
    Then eventual_cycle(f,x0) would return [8, 19, 17].
    (If the orbit of `x0` doesn't end up in a cycle, it's ok for this function t
    o run forever
    trying to find one.)
    """
    d = orbit_data(f,x0)
    cycle_value = dict("cycle")
    return cycle_value
```

an error kept popping up  I got an error dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required in my python program on both my questions

Comment: Please always post the **whole error message** with **full traceback**.

Comment: Share error logs, traceback

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `dict()` like that. You should provide the value as well:

```
dict(name="somebody", age=15)
```

Comment: sorry Something went wrong in calling steps_to_enter_cycle.
It was called as
  steps_to_enter_cycle(alpha,993)
where the function alpha is as shown below:
------------------------------
def alpha(x):
    "Collatz function"
    if x%2:
        return 3*x+1
    else:
        return x//2
------------------------------
Details about what went wrong are shown below.
dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
Test Failed: Function call failed.
that was the full error code